Trying to build a Singularity .sif file from a .def file referencing a local docker image - not working
I am trying to build a Singularity .sif file from a .def file referencing a local docker image. This is not working at all.
The error is:
FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: invalid image source: invalid reference format 

I have tried several iterations based on online instructions:
Bootstrap: docker
From: docker://my_image:latest

%environment
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/custom/path

%post
    echo "Post-installation script"

Bootstrap: docker
From: docker-daemon://my_image:latest

%environment
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/custom/path

%post
    echo "Post-installation script"

I can see my docker image:

sudo docker images

REPOSITORY                      TAG               IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
my_image               latest            d72053ddc119   2 hours ago     6.84GB

I have successfully done this via:

sudo singularity build test_container docker-daemon://my_image:latest

Why can't i do this with a .def file? I need to add in some post setup configurations, so this is incredibly frustrating it doesn't work
I am using Singularity version 3.6.4
Thanks
